# What educational qualifications are required to become a pilot in the UK?

Tags: commercial-aviation, career, uk

In order to obtain a pilot's licence in the UK, are any formal educational qualifications (such as school-leaving certificates) required?

As well as any statutory or other formal requirements, do employers of commercial pilots typically require any education qualifications? Or is holding a pilot's licence generally all that is needed?

In the absence of relevant educational qualifications, are there other skills, capacities or demonstrable advantages that would help someone who lacked them, but still hoped to become a pilot?

Comment: Do you mean just getting a private pilot's license, or becoming an airline pilot?

Comment: There's no GCSE or A-Level requirements for a pilot but you will have to pass a number of theory exams.  The usual path is PPL (private pilot's licence), CPL (commercial pilot's licence) and ATPL (Airline Transport Pilot's Licence).  You can get your PPL at age 17.  See here:  https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/EASA-requirements/PPL-SPL-BPL/Common-requirements-for-the-PPL,-SPL-and-BPL/

Comment: If you are looking to fly for airlines there are two methods of getting your ATPL, modular and integrated courses: https://www.pilotcareernews.com/pilot-training-integrated-vs-modular/  I've seen prices around £40k for modular to over £80k for integrated though these both seem a little low

Comment: nice edit, Daniele Procida!

Comment: As has been pointed out, there are requirements, but being fluent in the language is not one of them. Proficient is the requirement, with emphasis on aviation requirements. Other than that, and the obvious pilot training requirements, there are no formal education requirements for a pilot license. If you want to get a job as a pilot, the employer may have other requirements you must meet.

Answer (score 2):

There are no formal education requirements. However you must be fluent in English. The details can be found here https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/EASA-requirements/PPL-SPL-BPL/Common-requirements-for-the-PPL,-SPL-and-BPL/

Comment: Welcome to Aviation! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Commercial aviation I am interested in.

Comment: You don't have to be fluent in English. You have to pass a language proficiency test.